# Is there a web server running in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoose, mongo-java

When I start the config server I can see the following line in the logger:

```
[websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 27017
```

So, I wonder if mongo use a web server for maintaining config data?

Comment: Try accessing `http://MONGO_ADDRESS:28017/` eg: http://localhost:28017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(All of this assumes you're using the current version of MongoDB, 2.4 or higher)

No, MongoDB does not use a Web server in any way for configuration or administration (as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/)). There is a minimal web server for some other purposes however.

Configuration is done through configuration files or the command line when MongoDB is started.

There is a basic, optionally configured, web page that contains some statistics that may of interest to administrators documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-console) and called the Http Console. If enabled, it's available by default at `http://localhost:28017`. It can be disabled via the `nohttpinterface` option documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#nohttpinterface). Also, there is a *not recommended for production* REST api that can be used for some test and development tasks.

As an example,  I just confirmed that the `nohttpinterface` setting was not set to true in a configuration file (I have a custom port in this example as I have another MongoDB instance already running)

```
verbose=true
port=25017
```

I then started MongoDB. In the log file, this was present:

```
Thu Sep 26 11:11:06.645 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 26017
Thu Sep 26 11:11:06.645 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 25017
```

Then, I added the `nohttpinterface` option to the configuration file:

```
verbose=true
port=25017
nohttpinterface=true
```

After restarting MongoDB, I could not access the Http Console.  The web server was not started (there was no reference to the `websvr` in the log this time).

```
Thu Sep 26 11:11:34.028 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 25017
```

[image: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:26017]

Comment: Prairie I am able to view it through browser even if I make nohttpinterface=true and in my server it gets started at port 27017

Comment: What's "it" that you're viewing?

Comment: Prairie same as the http console in this page:http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-interface

Comment: It's @WiredPrairie. :) I just added `nohttpinterface=true` to a MongoDB configuration file. Started MongoDB. I could not access the Http Console. I then shut down MongoDB. I removed the line with `nohttpinterface` and restarted MongoDB. I then could access it. Try changing the default port to a different number: `port=25017`. The HttpConsole will be at a port 1000 higher, so `http://localhost:26017`.

Comment: my default port is on 26017 so I am able to access it in 27017,i stopped mongod,and than made nohhpinterface true,than again started mongod but i am able to access.I am using centos

Comment: Great! :) I added more evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mongodb has a built in admin interface. You can read up on the HTTP interface at
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-interface

Comment: is their anyway to disable it?I tried nohttpinterface but it doesn't work